# What does the percent sign indicate when used as a directory in batch files?

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I have made a few batch files the hard way by CD-ing into the directory by typing all the way from root drive to folder. I have seen a few example codes use percent signs enclosing a few key words and continue from there, eg:

```
%user_files%\programs\destination folder
```

They have always worked too.

Comment: try `ECHO %USERPROFILE%<ENTER>` try `SET<ENTER>`  try `SET a=abc` try `ECHO %a%`

Answer (score 0):

The different `%directory_name%` examples you see are called `Environment variables`. Normally, no matter how or where your Windows was installed, these environment variables are resolved by the command line interpreter (`CLI`) to the actual directories. E.g. `%userprofile%` will, on Windows 7, always point to `C:\Users\[username]\`, assuming your Windows was installed on the C:\ drive.

Comment: not necessarily a directory name